# Watin: Iterating through text boxes in a telerik gridview

Tags: c#-4.0, watin

I am currently developing a testing framework for a web data entry application that is using the Telerik ASP.Net framework and have run into a blocker.  If I step through my code in debug mode the test will find the text box that I am looking for and enter some test data and then save that data to the database. The problem that I am running into is that when I let the test run on it's own the test fails saying that it couldn't fine the column that was declared.  Here is my code:

```
/*Method to enter test data into cell*/
private TableCell EditFieldCell(string columnHeader)
{
 var columnIndex = ColumnIndex(columnHeader);

 if (columnIndex == -1)
    throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Column {0} not found.", columnHeader));

 return NewRecordRow.TableCells[columnIndex];
}

/*Method to return column index of column searching for*/
public int ColumnIndex(string columnHeader)
{
 var rgTable = GridTable;
 var rgCount = 0;
 var rgIndex = -1;

 foreach (var rgRow in rgTable.TableRows)
 {
      foreach (var rgElement in rgRow.Elements)
      {
       if (rgElement.Text != null)
       {
        if (rgElement.Text.Equals(columnHeader))
        {
          rgIndex = rgCount;
          break;
        }
       }
       rgCount++;
     }
 return rgIndex;
 }
```

My thinking is that something with my nested for loops is presenting the problem because the rgIndex value that is returned when I let the program run is -1 which tells me that the code in the for loops isn't being run.

TIA,
Bill Youngman

Answer (score 0):

Code that gets the table Column index. You need to pass the Table(verify that the table exists while debug):

```
 public int GetColumnIndex(Table table,  string headerName)
    {
        ElementCollection headerElements = table.TableRows[0].Elements; //First row contains the header
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var header in headerElements)
        {
            if (header.ClassName != null && header.ClassName.Contains(headerName)) //In this case i use class name of the header you can use the text
            {
                return counter;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        // If not found
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick although I did have to make a slight modification and look at header.Text instead of header.Class because the vendor who wrote this application did not do a very good job of using control id's or class id.